# How do I partition my on-premises network so one part can only access the external (internet)?

Tags: networking, juniper-junos, security

Currently, our setup is the following:

[image]

I need to make a change so there is no wireless access to our NAS.  The Wifi "passthrough" needs to only be able to communicate with the external internet connection (though through a firewalled router.)

I am relatively inexperienced with networking and would appreciate any help.

Comment: Unfortunately the consumer grade equipment you have won’t let you do what you want ( in addition to being off topic here).  You will need to replace them with commercial grade equipment to get the features you need.

Comment: I was under the impression the J-SRX100 was commercial grade.
I'll try to find a more suitable stack exchange site for my question.

Comment: You can try asking this question on [su].

Comment: @RonTrunk Since the main question revolves around the Dell router (Juniper OEM, should be on topic), I'd like to keep this question open for now.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is referred to as *zoning* - split your network into different security zones (and IP subnets), and use firewall rules to block or permit traffic between the zones.

You need to separate your network zones on the Dell router - either by using different VLANs or configuring the ports as routed/L3 ports, depending on the router's capability set. Separating zones on access switches would also be possible but requires *managed* switches with VLAN support.

Once you've done that, you can use firewall rules to permit and deny access to other parts of the network. For instance:

- permit workstation subnet access to anywhere
- deny WAP subnet access to private subnets but permit access to elsewhere (Internet).